# Gradually + have?

Tags: grammar

I've found examples in a dictionary,

*The British railway network has gradually been dismembered.
Gradually factory workers have been displaced by machines.*

Did the actions(dismembering and displacing) happen before and are they still going on?

Comment: Having just travelled from Cardiff to Glasgow via Crewe, I am surprised to learn the British railway network has been 'dismembered'. It looked fine to me.

Comment: Lol it's just an example from OALD! Do you think that the railway is still dismembering when you read that one?

Comment: @Yamato I don't know it.. I think it is real.

Comment: The first sentence could have been written after the [Beeching cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beeching_cuts) when many smaller railway lines were closed. Of course Britain still has a rail network and there are still people working in factories. If the writer wanted to stress that the process was still going on, they could use _is being dismembered_ and _are being replaced_.

Comment: True. Thank you Kate.

Answer (score -1):

It implies that there has been a process which continues until near the present, and has present relevance; but that present relevance might be that the process is continuing, or it might be that process has completed but its results are still current.

Comment: For example, you've quit playing tennis. You feel like you're forgetting how to play tennis (feel like you're losing the ability). What do you say?
I'm gradually forgetting how to play tennis. (Now you feel so?)
I have gradually forgotten how to play tennis. (Finished/forgot quite recently)

Comment: In that case, _I've gradually forgotten_ implies that the process is finished, and you've completely forgotten. However, "completely forgotten" isn't really a possibility, so it would mean that you've forgotten more than if you said _I'm gradually forgetting_.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.